# Converting time in number of minutes past midnight to HH:MM format

Tags: beginner, algorithm, c, datetime, formatting

This program is a clock that only displays minutes passed since midnight. This program is supposed to be really simple but because of some "aesthetic bug", I wrote quite a lot if-else statements that I think can be simplified.

---

> Format Input
>
> The first line will contain an integer `T`, the number of test cases.
>   Each test case will contain an number `N`, the number displayed by the
>   strange clock.
>
> Format Output
>
> For each test case, print “Case X: “ (X starts with 1) and then print
>   what time it is in 24 hours HH:MM format.
>
> Constraints
>
> 1 <= `T` <= 1000
>
> 0 <= `N` <= 1439

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int T;
    scanf("%d", &T);

    for (int i = 1; i <= T; i++) {

        int N;
        scanf("%d", &N);

        int hours = N / 60;
        int minutes = N % 60;

        printf("Case #%d: ", i);

        if (N < 10) {
            printf("00:0%d\n", N);
        } else if (N > 10 && N < 60) {
            printf("00:%d\n", N);
        } else if (N > 60 && N < 600) {
            if (minutes == 0) {
                printf("0%d:00\n", hours);
            } else if (minutes > 0 && minutes < 10) {
                printf("0%d:0%d\n", hours, minutes);
            } else {
                printf("0%d:%d\n", hours, minutes);
            }
        } else {
            if (minutes == 0) {
                printf("%d:00\n", hours);
            } else if (minutes > 0 && minutes < 10) {
                printf("%d:0%d\n", hours, minutes);
            } else {
                printf("%d:%d\n", hours, minutes);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I understand it, N is the number the clock must display, I.e. when N=1439, the clock should display 14:39. You should divide by 100 and not 60.

Comment: @Édouard since a day has 1440 minutes, it's more likely that N is the number of minutes since midnight. This crucial information is missing from the instructions, which probably prepares the students to real-life situations, which are very similar.

Comment: Or, the instructions may have included the definition of the "strange clock", and Elvan just didn't post this part.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Following @Martin R's comment, I'll make my comment above a solution:

`printf` already supports what you're trying to achieve with your if-then-else jungle:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int T;
    scanf("%d", &T);

    for (int i = 1; i <= T; i++) {

        int N;
        scanf("%d", &N);

        int hours = N / 60;
        int minutes = N % 60;

        printf("Case #%d: %02d:%02d\n", i, hours, minutes);
    }
}
```

You're also missing to check the return value of `scanf`. It is used to report errors in the input. What is the purpose of the first `scanf`?

**Edit**

From @chux's comment: you should validate the constraints of `N` after the input.

**Edit**

Note: additional variables should indeed have no influence on performance and are a good way to document meaning of your code, so please ignore my initial statement about "saving variables".

Old version was:

> Also, I'd change the variable naming. Use `minutes` instead of `N` to
>   communicate clearly what you're handling in the variable. You can then
>   write the computation directly in the parameter list of printf, saving
>   you two additional variables.

Comment: "saving you two additional variables" - in this case, I think the separated variables are actually a good idea. They shouldn't incur a performance drop, and they help to self-document the code.

Comment: _"Use `minutes` instead of N to communicate clearly what you're handling in the variable."_ The symbol N is explicitly defined in the problem statement. However, the word `minutes` could mean either N or the "minutes" field in the output.

Comment: Note that with input like `-61`, Output of `-01:00` might be preferred over this answer's `"-01:-01"`.  Yet with "0 <= N <= 1439" and  "minutes passed since midnight", we might not worry about yesterday.

Answer (score 10):

If your code is checked by an automated process, you will probably fail all test cases because your code prints a `#`, which was not asked for. You should better remove it. Just print "Case %d" instead of "Case #%d".